# VS Code outputs logs to terminal when launched with 'code' command

Tags: visual-studio-code, powershell-7.2

### Issue

VS Code outputs its logs to the PowerShell terminal from which it was launched using the `code .` command. Disabling these logs would be interesting as it populates a terminal instance for no good reason. I searched through Stackoverflow without success so far, so I hope there's not a duplicate out there.

Did anyone encounter this issue or have an idea in which direction I should be looking into? From what I've tried so far it seems that it's specific to PowerShell 7.

System: Windows 10, PowerShell 7
[image]

### What I've tried

- Uninstalling and reinstalling VS Code. Issue persists.
- Install VS Code insiders in parallel: it doesn't show the same issue.
- Try VS Code on a different machine: MacOS / Ubuntu: No issue, Windows 10 desktop (personal): No issue. My settings.json is synced between the different machines.
- Try other terminals: it only occurs on the powershell 7 terminal. CMD or the default Windows PowerShell doesn't have the same issue.
- Upgrade PowerShell 7 to latest. No solution.

What I would expect: No logs being outputted to the powershell terminal where code was launched.

Answer (score 0):

Just cancel the logging with CTRL z and press Enter. This worked for me.

The logs started showing after I reinstalled Python and changed the PATH in environment variables and added the location of VScode. Maybe knowing this can help find a long-term solution.

EDIT:

Just to add, this is temporary and when I close the terminal, the VScode instance closes too.